# Why does document.createTextNode() not allow setAttribute()?

Tags: javascript

So while working with the dom, I came across the situation where I assumed that the object resulting from `document.createTextNode()` would be treated in a similar way to an object resulting from `document.createElement();`, in that I would be able to call `setAttribute()` on it.

Example:

```
var genericElementNode = document.createElement('p');
genericElementNode.setAttribute('id', 'sampleId1');
// The above will run fine


var textNode = document.createTextNode("Hello World");
textNode.setAttribute('id', 'sampleId2');
//The above will result in an error:
//Uncaught TypeError: textNode.setAttribute is not a function
```

Why is this the case? And are there any workarounds?

Comment: Text nodes are not elements, and therefore have a [different prototype](https://developer.mozilla.org/docs/Web/API/Node). --- `setAttribute` is a method of `HTMLElement`, which `textNode` does not inherit from.

Comment: _"are there any workarounds?"_ What is your end goal?

Comment: @evolutionxbox It would be excellent if you could expand that into an answer. Also, do you have any idea why textNode is not a 'node', despite being named as such. Why isn't it called something more appropriate?

Answer (score 7):

you cant set/get  any of attributes/elements of textNode

> are there any workarounds?

it's easy to say creating element inside such as `span` and set your text

```
var genericElementNode = document.createElement('p');
genericElementNode.setAttribute('id', 'sampleId1');
// The above will run fine


var textNode = document.createElement("span");
textNode.innerText = "Hello World";
textNode.setAttribute('id', 'sampleId2');
```

Answer (score 1):

[`document.createTextNode`](https://developer.mozilla.org/docs/Web/API/Document/createTextNode) returns exactly that... a Text Node, which inherits from [`Node`](https://developer.mozilla.org/docs/Web/API/Node). This does not have the `setAttribute` method.

An [`Element`](https://developer.mozilla.org/docs/Web/API/Element), which can be created using [`document.createElement`](https://developer.mozilla.org/docs/Web/API/Document/createElement), also inherits from `Node`, but it also has a bunch more methods including [`setAttribute`](https://developer.mozilla.org/docs/Web/API/Element/setAttribute).

---

As [@Mamdouh Freelancer](https://stackoverflow.com/users/7040620/mamdouh-freelancer) has stated,  you can instead use an inline level element such as a `span`.

```
var textNode = document.createElement('span');
textNode.textContent = 'Hello world';
textNode.setAttribute('id', 'sampleId2');
```